# Java Streams - replace nested for loops with Streams and return value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wonder how to replace this old school for loops with Java Streams:

```
public Long getStoreid(){
    for (PointDto point : tw.getPath().getPoints())) {
        for (PointOperationDto operation : point.getOperations()) {
            if (operation.isIncluded() {
                return point.getStoreId();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get `storeId` in the best possible way.\

**UPDATE**

After your answers the working version is:

```
tw.getPath().getPoints().stream()
                .filter(point -> point.getOperations().stream().anyMatch(PointOperation::isIncluded))
                .map(point::getStoreId)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
```

but now the question is how to use eg. `Optional.ofNullable()` to prevent NPE error because `tw.getPath()` can be null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need that:

```
tw.getPath().getPoints().stream()
        .filter(point -> point.getOperations().stream().anyMatch(Operation::isIncluded))
        .map(Point::getStoreId)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(0L);
```

Comment: findFirst() might better translate the current implementation by OP.

Comment: YES! That is what I was looking for - I have to use anyMatch()... Thank you

Comment: @Dmitrii Bykov One more question - how to use Optional.ofNullable to prevent NPE error? tw.getPath() can be NULL... I tried with Optional.ofNullable(tw.getPath() but actually I don't have idea how to use it in this case

Comment: Optional.ofNullable(tw.getPath()).orElseGet(Collections.emptyList()).getPoints().stream() i think you need it

Comment: Hmm but this method returns Long storeId.. SonarLint complains about.orElseGet(null) bcause I can't set null and my method has to return Long or null

Comment: when you will use orElseGet() you should return Long or null, that's right. You also can use orElseThrow() and throw an exception. I don't know your logic. What do you want to return null or anyLong or throw exception...

Answer (score 2):

The following operations are needed: `map`, `filter`, and `findFirst`:

```java
public Long getStoreid() {
    return tw.getPath().getPoints().stream()
            .filter(Objects::isNonNull) // optional filter to prevent NPE
            .map(point -> point.getOperations().stream()
                .filter(Objects::isNonNull) // optional filter to prevent NPE
                .filter(PointOperationDto::isIncluded)
                .findFirst()
                .map(op -> point.getStoreId())
            )
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);
}
```